# Deflate: uncompressing a PNG without zlib (or any other library)

Tags: c, png, deflate

The other day, I thought that I would learn more about image compression. I looked into .png and its respective compression algorithm and I would like to be able to uncompress the file without any other library as a way for me to learn more about data compression. I am having a difficult time finding info on how to decompress a png without a third-party library and was hoping someone may be able to either point me in the right direction or briefly explain it.

Comment: Why don't you take a look at the third party lib's?

Comment: Well, you could start with [RFC 1951](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1951), which specifies the zlib compression algorithm (also known as "DEFLATE")

Comment: @IanCarroll As the OP said: "without any other library **as a way for me to learn more about data compression**."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd start with reading about the DEFLATE compression for example on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE) or [RFC 1951](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951#section-Abstract) as this is the base of the PNG compression (at least according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Compression)). There is also a brief explaination of the filtering which preceeds the DEFLATE is available.

Comment: I've already read the wikipedia page. I'll look at the RFC page though and let you know what I find

Comment: @ChaseWalden Look also on the reference list of the wikipedia article. There you'll find plenty of resources related to PNG (even the RFC and the format specification is linked there)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to decompress the deflate data, you'll need to be able to find it.  So you should first learn about the [structure of PNG files](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/iso/index-object.html).  Then see other answer.

Comment: I already have a parser written that extracts all of the information from the header and then extracts the compressed image data into an array.